# Award badges for a quantity of well-received answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

Where can new badges be suggested?

Android Enthusiasts' value mostly comes from people providing (quality) answers.

Immediately (in my opinion) the most natural badge came to my mind but I couldn't find an equivalent:

- bronze: answered  100 questions with score x
- silver: answered  500 questions with score x
- gold:   answered 2500 questions with score x

Name: Problem solver/...

Comment: This site or [Meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) are probably both fine for suggestions like new badges. The Stack Exchange community managers keep an eye on both, and they're likely the ones that would need to give the suggestion a stamp of approval (well, them and ultimately the devs).

Comment: Ok, cool. I then assume it's fine to just keep this question open until some Ops come along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This *almost* already exists](https://android.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags):

> - Gold Tag Badge
>     You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
> - Silver Tag Badge
>     You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
> - Bronze Tag Badge
>     You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, my bad. I must have skipped this too quickly by spotting 'wiki'...